# Apache Flink: Cannot find compatible factory for specified execution.target (=local)

Tags: apache-flink

I've decided to experiment with apache flink a bit. I decided to use scala console (or more precisely http://ammonite.io/) to read some stuff from csv file and print it locally... just to debug end experiments.

```scala
import $ivy.`org.apache.flink:flink-csv:1.10.0`
import $ivy.`org.apache.flink::flink-scala:1.10.0`

import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.api.scala.extensions._

val env = ExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment()
val lines = env.readCsvFile[(String, String, String)]("/home/slovic/Dokumenty/test.csv")
lines.collect()
//java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot find compatible factory for specified execution.target (=local)
//org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:104)
//org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(ExecutionEnvironment.java:937)
//org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:860)
//org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:844)
//org.apache.flink.api.scala.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.scala:495)
//org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet.collect(DataSet.scala:739)
//ammonite.$sess.cmd24$.<init>(cmd24.sc:1)
//ammonite.$sess.cmd24$.<clinit>(cmd24.sc)
```

What I need to do to run this code locally? (tested with scala 2.11 & 2.12)

**EDIT: SOLLUTION BY Piyush_Rana**
We need additional import:

```
import $ivy.`org.apache.flink::flink-streaming-scala:1.10.0`  //Piyush_Rana's advice. !!!FIX!!!
```

Comment: remove the first  env.execute("test")  .
you cant execute flink program withot sink or print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also got the same error and figured out that was missing one dependency -

```scala
val flinkVersion = "1.10.0"
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala" % flinkVersion,
```

or in ammonite repl:

```scala
import $ivy.`org.apache.flink::flink-streaming-scala:1.10.0`
```

Comment: I got the same error while updating from flink 1.9 to 1.10. This didn;t help me. I already have said dependency :(

Answer (score 1):

You didnt execute the flink program .

Try to add  execute command at the end.

```
 env.execute("unique name")
```

Comment: lines.collect() already calls execute() for us internally (as shown on stacktrace).